# PHP Functions on page with URL rewrite?

Tags: php, mysql, url, pdo

On my website I have a dropdown of counties...

```
<form method="post" action="/people.php" >
            <select name="county" onchange="this.form.submit()" >
                <option>--Select a County--</option>
                <option value="Avon">Avon</option>
                <option value="Bedfordshire">Bedfordshire</option>
                <option value="Berkshire">Berkshire</option>
            </select>
</form>
```

I then have my query on my people page...

```
$county = $_POST['county'];

$sth = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM directory WHERE user_active != '' AND County = :county");
$sth->execute(array(':county' => $county));
```

I want to use URL rewrites to include the county in my url, so when you go to the page after selecting a county it doesnt display like

```
'www.mysite.com/people.php'
```

but shows as

```
'www.mysite.com/people-in-avon'
```

Im still very much a newbie at PHP but, if I want to do this, will I need to use GET method, and post my data to a php page, ***that then*** redirects to people.php? Is it bad practice in PHP to have the queries on page?

I hope this makes sense?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You first need to use an .htaccess with some basic redirections to be able to use people-in-[country] URLs.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^people-in-(.*) /people.php?county=$1 [L]
```

In your people.php :

```
<?php

// you county is set in GET via the .htaccess
$county = $_GET['county'];

// database query
$sth = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM directory WHERE user_active != '' AND County = :county");
$sth->execute(array(':county' => $county));

?>
```

To create the URL, you should replace special characters, accents, space...
But if your counties are in one word, without special characters, you could just do :

```
<?php 

// to redirect
$county = $_POST['county'];
$url = '/people-in-' . $county;
// redirect
header('Location:' . $url);
```

To retrieve by ID your county, you could do something like that (pseudo code):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^people-in-.*-([0-9]+) /people.php?county_id=$1 [L]
```

To show the county :

```
// you county_id is set in GET via the .htaccess
$county_id = $_GET['county_id'];
```

To route to the county :

```
// to redirect
$county_id = $_POST['county_id'];

// fetch the county by id
// BASIC string cleaning
$county = str_replace(' ', '-', $county);

$url = '/people-in-' . $county . '-' . $county_id;

// redirect
header('Location:' . $url);
```

Comment: i dont think your answer is obvious to the OP that the redirect needs to take place after submitting. IE the post form `action="/_people.php"` and that `_people.php` should include the redirect..

Comment: I picked up on that @DannyHearnah, thanks for the heads up though!

Comment: 1 issue I have however...

$url = '/missing-people-in-' . $county;

If the county is double barralled, say 'east sussex' It isnt being seperated with a dash, Have you any idea how this is done?

Comment: I usually work with toAsciiAndUnderscore methods to clean my string. This way "east sussex" become "people-in-east-sussex". The result will be a more difficult job to retrieve the county (because the string has changed), the technique is now to add the id to the url (faster/easier but not always pretty). Please see my edit.

Answer (score 1):

Use this

```
<form method="post" action="/people.php" >
            <select name="county" id="selectform" >
                <option>--Select a County--</option>
                <option value="Avon">Avon</option>
                <option value="Bedfordshire">Bedfordshire</option>
                <option value="Berkshire">Berkshire</option>
            </select>
</form>
```

in java script

```
<script>
 $(document).ready(function(){
 $("#selectform").change(function(){
  window.location="www.mysite.com/people-in-"+$(this).val()+";
 })
</script>
```

and `.htaccess` file use this

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule   ^people-in-(.*) people.php?option=$1  [QSA,L]
```

and in `people.php`

```
$value=explode("-",$_GET['option']);
$newvalue=$value[2];
```